# Nested CSV - Mule DataWeave

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I have a CSV like this:

```
data1,data2,data3;dataa;datab;datac;datax,datay,dataz
data1,data2,data3;dataa;datab;datac;datax,datay,dataz
data1,data2,data3;dataa;datab;datac;datax,datay,dataz
```

I use spliter to process the records line by line, further I use splitBy "," in dataweave to convert the record to a map. But how I can do another level of split for ";" ? SplitBy doesnt allow muliple delimiters so do the CSV type in dataweave.

Ultimately, I want a JSON like this:

```
{
   "1":"data1",
   "2":"data2",
   "3":{
      "a":"dataa",
      "b":"datab",
      "c":"datac"
   },
   "x":"datax",
   "y":"datay",
   "z":"dataz "
}
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: The expected JSON result is invalid. Did you mean like this?

    {
      "1": "data1",
      "2": "data2",
      "3": {
        "a": "dataa",
        "b": "datab",
        "c": "datac"
      },
      "x": "datax",
      "y": "datay",
      "z": "dataz"
    }

Comment: Oops , my typo. Yes you are right .

Answer (score 3):

Try the following DataWeave code:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map {
    "1": $[0],
    "2": $[1],
    "3": using (detail = $[2] splitBy ";") {
        a: detail[1],
        b: detail[2],
        c: detail[3]
    },
    x: $[3],
    y: $[4],
    z: $[5]
}
```

Notes:

- I modified the input data to separate `datac` and `datax`. Replace the `;` character with `,` e.g.: `...;datab;datac,datax,...`
- I use *File* connector to read the CSV file, and directly process it in *DataWeave* transformer (do not use a *Splitter*)

Comment: I mainly use splitter because, it splits the records line by line. Further I process the record using dataweave. But as per your recommendation, can I achieve the same ? Can data weave take care of streaming ? Basically, the file size is not certain in my use case

Answer (score 1):

I want to observe, that your JSON example has bad structure!
In this JSON the 4th element is an object and it hasn't a key, just value...
First of all, u should validate your end JSON.
Example of your valid JSON:
[image]

When u validate your JSON, I'll try to help in convering your CSV data to the JSON.

Comment: I have fixed the data, can you take a look now ?